# Python regex does not match. I cant handle it

Tags: python, regex

why this match does not work ? The problem is with D

```
import re

A = [0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff]
B = [0xa8, 0x2c, 0x53, 0x20, 0xca, 0x62, 0x49, 0x13]
C = [0x1A, 0xC4, 0x17, 0x05, 0x47, 0xE8, 0xA3, 0x83]
D = [0x81, 0x63, 0x1f, 0x55, 0xdb, 0x18, 0x2a, 0xab]


for bin_header in [A, B, C, D]:
    bin_str = ''.join(map(chr, bin_header))
    r = re.match(bin_str, bin_str)
    if not r:
        print map(hex, bin_header) # Surprise it prints D
```

Comment: Where is your regex?

Comment: Why are you using regex in the first place?!

Comment: Saleem: re.match(bin_str, bin_str)

Comment: `0x2a` is an asterisk `'*'`. Asterisks are not matched like normal characters in regex. The pattern `'\x81c\x1fU\xdb\x18*\xab'` does not match itself.

Comment: Biffen: it does not matter I need solution with this aproach. I am matching binary string.

Comment: @se7en Not sure I understand what you're saying, but if you want to compare ‘binary strings’ (whatever that means), then why not just compare them? Why use regex?

Comment: Why are you matching a pattern string with itself?  This will not work. see comment of @khelwood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to match a string with a regular expression, but ignoring the regular expression syntax. Here is your problem:

```
>>> chr(0x2a)
'*'
```

The `*` has special meaning in regular expression syntax. `"abc*"` the regular expression won't match `"abc*"` the string (it will match `"abcccc"` for example).

I suggest you use `=` or `x in y` not `re.match` for this. Passing random bytes to a regular expression isn't a great idea if you don't know that they are all valid characters, or even what the characters are.

Here's an example using `in`:

```
import re

A = [0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff]
B = [0xa8, 0x2c, 0x53, 0x20, 0xca, 0x62, 0x49, 0x13]
C = [0x1A, 0xC4, 0x17, 0x05, 0x47, 0xE8, 0xA3, 0x83]
D = [0x81, 0x63, 0x1f, 0x55, 0xdb, 0x18, 0x2a, 0xab]


for bin_header in [A, B, C, D]:
    bin_str = ''.join(map(chr, bin_header))
    matches =  bin_str in bin_str
    if not matches:
        print map(hex, bin_header) # Matches all examples.
```

Even so, constructing strings from unknown byte streams won't play nicely with character encodings, and you should use the correct methods for working with byte sequences.

If you really want to use strings for this, you could represent them as hex strings. As hex strings are only `0-9a-z` you could safely use any string or regular expression matching etc.

```
for bin_header in [A, B, C, D]:
    bin_str = ''.join('%02x' % i for i in bin_header)
    matches =  bin_str in bin_str
    print(bin_str, matches)
    if not matches:
        print map(hex, bin_header)
```

gives

```
('ffffffffffffffff', True)
('a82c5320ca624913', True)
('1ac4170547e8a383', True)
('81631f55db182aab', True)
```